# Grub and Windows on L

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have recently installed Ubuntu 15.10 on a Lenovo Ideapad 300. All works fine. I have dual booted this so I can use Windows 10 for some old software.

When I boot I get into the grub menu. Choosing Ubuntu works fine, but when choosing Windows the Windows boot manager fails with the text:
The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors.

I Have found a peculiar "work around", if I enter "c" and get into the grub command line and then enter "exit", Windows 10 boots up as needed. Is there any way to fix this without this work around?

Answer (score 0):

Does you have windows option in boot menu. Try to repair the boot. First log into ubuntu and execute these commands in commandline:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

type boot-repair in terminal or search in Dash. Run boot-repair by clicking on it. select "Recommended repair". When repair finish note the url that appear and reboot.Check with booting to window. If not successful indicate the url to people who can help you.